# Microsoft JScript runtime error when using "Use Local IIS Web Server"

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, crash, jscript

Everything was working fine until someone in a Microsoft forum had try a couple devenv switches in command prompt mode: devenv /Resetsettings and Run devenv /ResetSkipPkgs.Prompt for an unrelated problem, namely that I could not save aspx files with one click of the save button.  Ever since then, I am running into a new problem.

I tried uninstalling VS2012, rebooting, and reinstalling to no avail.

The problem is that I receive a Microsoft JScript runtime error when using the "Use Local IIS Web Server" setting.  IIS cannot find variables defined in files it loaded.  When I run with the "Use Visual Studio Development Server" option, then it works.

Why is that and how can I get the "Use Local IIS Web Server" working again.

2 images showing the problem.
[image: Actual Error Messages]
[image: Actual code and Solution Explorer showing files]

(I uploaded the images yesterday, not sure what happened.)

I am not sure what to make of the problem.  I saw another post on a different forum regarding a similar issue.

Comment: *"...local IIS that Visual Studio uses seems to not handle Javascript anymore for whatever reason."* Can you clarify this statement? Are you saying that when you view source on any browser, the JS links aren't there (in the source)? How are you referencing the files (show code)? If the links are in view source, then it's more likely a path error or an error in the js itself (if it 'doesn't work")....

Comment: Code is not the problem, doing the reset is.  I thought that it was a mistake to do that, as my problem was with saving.  Please see my edited post for code samples.

Comment: I rewrote the issue to be more technical, now that I know more about the problem and give screenshots showing the problem.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: The exception shown on the first screen is indicative of an extension gone bad. You could follow the instructions in that dialog and start visual studio with /log flag and check the logs. The steps regarding the other flags were appropriate for that exception. You may want to start VS using `devenv.exe /SafeMode` and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: your jwplayer is referenced using an absolute path. in integrated debugging web server your webapp is hosted as root `/`, working fine. in iis, you most likely host it in a virtual subdirectory, so you need to dynamically add that to your absolute (script) paths. the acutal script error seems legit, so vs does definitely do debug js.

Answer (score 1):

0x800a1391 Error Codes are caused in one way or another by misconfigured system files in your windows operating system.

The 0x800a1391 error may be caused by windows system files damage. 
There can be many events which may have resulted in the system files errors. An incomplete installation, an incomplete uninstall, improper deletion of applications or hardware.

I would sincerely say that you should either restore your computer to an earlier time before you had played with devenv switches. They did nothing but corrupt you system files and created a bug inside to halt the program from retrieving data for javascript code to execute.

http://www.wiki-errors.com/wiki-errors.php?wiki=0x800a1391
You can always visit this wiki article to download the error detection tool to help you on assisting the error correction